# Error 'USER_PROJECT_DENIED' when trying to list the unused service accounts in gcp

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I am trying to list unused service accounts in a gcp project

Working fine when using gcloud command

```
gcloud recommender insights list \
    --insight-type=google.iam.serviceAccount.Insight \
    --location=global \
    --filter=insightSubtype=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USAGE --project
```

Getting an error when i am trying to list the unused service accounts using python sdk. Below is the error

```
import requests
import json
import re
import sys
import subprocess
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account


credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("")
service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
request = service.projects().list()
token1 = subprocess.Popen("gcloud auth print-access-token", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
token, error = token1.communicate()
token = str(token.decode("utf-8"))
token = token.rstrip("\n")
token = token.rstrip("\r")

while request is not None:
    response = request.execute()
    print(response)
    for project in response.get('projects', []):
        projectid = project['projectId']
        projectname = project['name']

        headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        'x-goog-user-project': projectname
        }
        post_url= "https://recommender.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + projectid + "/locations/"+ "global" +"/insightTypes/google.iam.serviceAccount.Insight/insights?filter=insightSubtype=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USAGE"
        post_url_data = requests.get(post_url, headers = headers)
        get_api_json = json.loads(post_url_data.text)
        print(get_api_json)
```

I am iterating through all projects, for some projects i am getting below  error, I have checked in the console, the projects exist..

```
Error: project not found or deleted, status; INVALID_ARGUMENT, details: [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc/ErrorInfo', 'reason':'USER_PROJECT_DENIED'
```

Any idea what's missing here?

Comment: Plz edit your question and include the code (remove sensitive data). Also show how do you authenticate the python client lib and list the permissions given to the `identity` that is authenticated.

Comment: I have included the code..

Answer (score 0):

the error means that you have insufficient permissions on the **user project** or it is deleted or not found.

A User Project is for quota and billing purposes. The caller must have the IAM permission **serviceusage.services.use** permission on the project. The user/quota project is set with this command:

```
gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `project_id` in your requests unless otherwise specified in documentation.

Notice the change in your code:

```
for project in response.get('projects', []):
    projectid = project['projectId']
    projectname = project['name']

    headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    'x-goog-user-project': projectid # >>> HERE <<<, use projectid instead of projectname and make sure you have the required permission/s
    }
    post_url= "https://recommender.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + projectid + "/locations/"+ "global" +"/insightTypes/google.iam.serviceAccount.Insight/insights?filter=insightSubtype=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USAGE"
    post_url_data = requests.get(post_url, headers = headers)
    get_api_json = json.loads(post_url_data.text)
    print(get_api_json)
```

Comment: @usertj You are welcome. if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.